# Join multiple list on property in parallel

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to join multiple list with same type on property in parallel.
Let say I have three list like below.

**List 1**

```
 id |Name  |Phone|Address
 1  |John  |NULL |NULL
 2  |David |NULL |NULL
```

**List 2**

```
 id |Name  |Phone|Address
 1  |NULL  |1234 |NULL
 2  |NULL  |5678 |NULL
```

**List 3**

```
 id|Name|Phone|Address
 1 |NULL|NULL |Plant ave
 2 |NULL|NULL |Earth ave
```

I want to join three tables on ID in to a new list like,

**New List**

```
 id|Name |Phone|Address
 1 |John |1234 |Plant ave
 2 |David|5678 |Earth ave
```

This is what I got so far, `lists.AsParallel().ForEach(JoinLists)` but I can't go further.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit**

This is what I did to join list. Not parallel.

```
       var newList = from l1 in list1
                join l2 in list2 on l1.Id equals l2.Id
                join l3 in list3 on l1.Id equals l3.Id
                select new 
                {
                    Id= l1.Id,
                    Name= li.Name,
                    Phone= l2.Phone,
                    Address = l3.Address 
                };
```

Comment: why do you want yo do it in parallel?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver Because speed is most important. In reality, each list will have more than 10000+ rows.

Comment: Have you tried doing it *not* in parallel, and checked that that's too slow? You should be able to join hundreds of thousands of rows very quickly in LINQ to Objects - it will take a lot of memory, but that will be the case using parallelization too.

Comment: For other questions: 1) do you *always* want to take just the name from list 1, the phone from list 2 and the address from list 3? What if there's data in other columns? 2) do you need to join on ID, or are the lists already in ID order with the exact same rows in every list?

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree. It wasn't slow but I want to make it faster

Comment: That suggests you've got working code with it not happening in parallel. It would be *really* helpful if you'd show that code...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, take only specific property from each list. And i need to join on ID. ID is a unique value something like Customer Id etc

Comment: Right. So it would be helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] showing what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see my edit. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: That looks fairly reasonable. So, have you tried just taking that code and using `.AsParallel()` onto `list1`, `list2` and `list3`, i.e. `from l1 in list1.AsParallel() join l2 in list2.AsParallel() on l1.Id equals l2.Id` etc... It's not clear why you're trying to use `ForEach`.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, i didn't know i can use `AsParallel()` like you said.

Comment: @JonSkeet It seems like it became faster. Thank you! But do you have better suggestion? I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Nope, that's basically the way to do parallel joins, as far as I'm aware...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok. Thank you. Could you copy your comments into answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to parallelize your existing join. That's as simple as adding `.AsParallel()` to each source:

```
var newList = from l1 in list1.AsParallel()
              join l2 in list2.AsParallel() on l1.Id equals l2.Id
              join l3 in list3.AsParallel() on l1.Id equals l3.Id
              select new 
              {
                  Id= l1.Id,
                  Name= li.Name,
                  Phone= l2.Phone,
                  Address = l3.Address 
              };
```

As usual, you shouldn't assume anything about the *ordering* of the results - but if you don't care about that, this should be faster on suitable hardware. (It will be slightly less efficient overall though, of course. It still needs to do the same work, with added overhead for parallelization.)